# Can I Change a recommendation letter provider after being invited for Campus interview?

Tags: recommendation-letter

I have recently received a campus interview for a Faculty position ECE (I had applied for the position much earlier time). They invite me just by looking my CV (Top 100 ECE schools of US). Currently, I am working with two postdoc supervisors (outside US). While we were in the process of setting the interview date, the university has asked my reference providers to submit their letter. Two of my references have provided letters (one PhD supervisor and one Postdoc supervisor). However the other postdoc supervisor is not willing to provide a letter.

The application requires me to provide 3 names of references. Now my questions are

1. Is it good to ask the committee chair to change the name of reference at this stage?
2. Could the school change their decision not to proceed with me (i.e., cancel the invitation).
3. Will they inform me give them alternative reference?

Thanks

Comment: _However the other postdoc supervisor is not willing to provide a letter._ -- So then why did you include their name in your application?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I worked with him for one year. During this period, we had some differences on different aspects of the research. I have tried my best to publish my work at difference top journals. I chose a topic of what I like (in our research area). And I have found constructive comments from reviewers. I guess he did not like this approach. This makes our relationship not to move smoothly. Nevertheless, he still renewed my work contract. For this reason, I did not suspect any thing negative from him (to the level where he will not write letters).

Comment: When I checked my applications 1 month ago, I have noticed that his letters are not submitted in many of my applications. That is why I become aware lately. And I ask him to write a letter by summarizing what I did for the last 1 year. He said “This research is only your research”. I write three papers and he blocked me from submission deliberately without a clear reason (I promised him to be responsible for any kind of review outcome). In addition, he asks me to work with one PhD student for paper submission and share my code. But I will not be included in the Authorship.

Comment: But the student was surprized and told me the sympathy about this action. However, it was not surprise for me. Please note that I also ask him to leave the Lab in 2-3 month time, if he is not happy with me. He said “no”. Now I realize that he wants to keep me just to hurt my publication and CV. Please also note that I have also seen several non-academic mentalities from him (getting papers published by contact, and telling me that CV is not important to get a job etc).

Comment: The issue is “no one is willing to listen my reason” at this stage. That is why I am worried about this interview. I would appreciate if I can get help to resolve this complication. Thanks

Comment: You've committed a serious faux pas. You **must** ask potential references directly if they are willing to write you strong recommendation letters **before** listing them as references.  Even if the potential reference is your PhD advisor or postdoc supervisor.  If they don't immediately say "yes of course", run like the wind.